# Sharepoint REST API + unable to Update Extended properties

Tags: sharepoint

Currently we are consuming Sharepoint 2013 REST API; As per requirement we need to update certain extended properties. e.g. "IsCompleted" property of workflow.

Currently we are using following link for rest api
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx

Can you please help out to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a read only property. You cannot update it. There is no setter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflow.iscompleted(v=office.15).aspx

And logically too, this property would reflect the current state of workflow. To mark it completed, you would have to complete the workflow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. so how to complete workflow using REST API? Is there any REST API method for this ? Please help out

Comment: It depends on your workflow. If your workflow requires, approving/rejecting. Then user would have to complete that operation. Also you would have to check if those Approval/rejections are exposed via REST API. I doubt that workflow operations are not exposed via REST